# Show the following is a measure verify

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $P(X)$ be the power set of some finite, non empty subset $X$.
Define $\mu: P(X)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ by

$\mu(B)=\frac{|B|}{|X|}$.

Is $\mu$ a measureon $X$?

My attempt:

Yes, clearly, $\mu(\varnothing)=0$.

Let $A_1,.....,A_n.....$ be members of $P(X)$ that are pairwise disjoint. Since $P(X)$ is finite, we can only have finitely many $A_i's$. That is, $A_1,......,A_n$ (with the other members being the empty set). Then,

$\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)=\frac{|A_1|+.......+|A_n|}{|X|}=\frac{|A_1|}{|X|}+......+\frac{|A_n|}{|X|}$

hence yes, it is a measure.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. This is just multiplying the cardinality measure on finite sets by a constant.

Comment: It is good to know that this is sometimes called ‘normalizing a measure’. Note that $\mu(X)=1$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The only small improvement is: "Since $P(X)$ is finite, we can only have finitely many **non-empty** $A_i's$".